# C#でファイルをクリップボードへ切り取る方法

Tags: c#, winforms

お世話になっております。
C#でクリップボードへファイルを切り取りたいと思い、下記のようなコードを作成しました。

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

string[] filelist = {"D:\\test1.txt", "C:\\test2.txt"};
IDataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, filelist);
byte[] bs = new byte[] { (byte)DragDropEffects.Move, 0, 0, 0 };
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bs);
data.SetData("Preferred DropEffect", ms);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data);
```

しかし、このコードの場合、ファイルを切り取ったあとに、アプリケーションを終了してしまうと、クリップボードから貼り付けできなくなってしまいます。
アプリケーション終了後でもファイルを貼り付けできるようにするには、どのような方法がありますでしょうか。
何か方法があれば、教えていただけますと幸いです。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

第2引数にtrueを指定することでデータをアプリケーションが終了してもクリップボードに残しておくことができます。[(参考)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.setdataobject?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Clipboard_SetDataObject_System_Object_System_Boolean_)

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。完全に調査不足でした。うまく動きました。